# Nested list - create new nested list with indices as items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to create a new nested list from an already existing nested list. This new list should include the indices+1 from the existing list.

Example:

```
my_list = [[20, 45, 80],[56, 29],[76],[38,156,11,387]]
```

Result:

```
my_new_list = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[1,2,3,4]]
```

How can I create such a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save a python loop, force iteration of `range` (required for python 3) in a list comprehension, so it's faster than a classical double nested comprehension:

```
my_list = [[20, 45, 80],[56, 29],[76],[38,156,11,387]]

index_list = [list(range(1,len(x)+1)) for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do this, but the first that comes to mind is to enumerate the elements with a starting index of `1` in a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> [[index for index, value in enumerate(sub, 1)] for sub in my_list]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: in that case, underscore the value: `[[index for index, _ in enumerate(sub, 1)] for sub in my_list]`

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the quick answer. Works perfectly :)

Comment: I'd say `enumerate` is not ideal here as you don't need to extract index *and* value.

Comment: @ean-François Fabre why should I use the underscore instead? Would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @jpp What should I use instead of `enumerate` then?

Comment: @julius.d, `range`, see Jean-Francois' answer.

Comment: @julius.d the "_" means that you're not using the variable. It's a placeholder to unpack it and discard it. Idiomatic python.

Answer (score 0):

## Using nested list comprehension

First you want a list with every number from 1 to the length of your sublist. There are several ways to do this with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

For example

```
[i for i in range(1, len(sublist) + 1)]
```

or

```
[i + 1 for i in range(len(sublist))]
```

Second you want to do this for every sublist inside your `my_list`. Therefore you have to use nested list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [[20, 45, 80],[56, 29],[76],[38,156,11,387]]
>>> my_new_list = [[i+1 for i in range(len(sublist))] for sublist in my_list]
>>> my_new_list
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

## Using list comprehension with range

Another way would be using the [range built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as a generator for your sublists:

```
>>> [list(range(1, len(sublist) + 1)) for sublist in my_list]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

## Using map with range

Or you can use the [map built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> list(map(
...     lambda sublist: list(range(1, len(sublist) + 1)),
...     my_list
... ))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
new_list = [list(range(1,len(item)+1)) for item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is are some simple solutions:

```
>>> lst = [[20, 45, 80],[56, 29],[76],[38,156,11,387]]   
>>> out = [[x+1 for x,_ in enumerate(y)] for y in lst]
>>> out
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>>
>>>
>>> out = [[x+1 for x in range(len(y))] for y in lst]
>>> out
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```